# Change label in views php

Tags: views

I am using the views php module and want a custom label.

The label field doesn't allow php to be entered, how would I go about changing the label?

Comment: Could you explain why do you feel you need a PHP code there?

Comment: It is a table that shows data for 12 weeks. Each column should have that weeks date displayed as the label

Comment: Hello again :) Remember, on this site it is always better to edit your question than to comment. It's not a forum and most people will not read comments before judging if your problem is worth their time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

In the view UI, choose a php field type

[image]

and your custom php code can be entered here:

[image]

Comment: But how do I put php in the label field?

Comment: You can't. Php is for each row. The label is a single value for the column's title. Your column's title has the be unique for your view, what iss changing is the rows no ?

Comment: I need the label to change based on the date selected to display the proper week as the label